# In a multiple linear regression, why are my coefficients all -1?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, python, multivariate-analysis

(EDIT: [Here's the Jupyter notebook behind this.](https://github.com/arm5077/iowa-simulation/blob/master/Iowa%20caucus%20simulation.ipynb))

I'm working with a simulated dataset of an election with six candidates and two voting rounds. (It's modeled after the Iowa caucuses.)

In this hypothetical election, once people cast their first ballot, the totals are revealed and they're allowed to change their votes once. So if they selected a candidate that performed poorly, they could swing their vote to a more successful competitor.

I've mapped a new dataset from this data, where each row is a single voting precinct, and each column is how much (in percentage points) a given candidate's vote percentage shifted between the first and second rounds.

**I want to use multiple linear regression to determine the likeliest flow of voters between the two rounds**. My thought is that if hold one candidate as `y` and the remaining five as `x`, the coefficients will tell me how each fared against the control candidate.

However, when I run this analysis, **the coefficients for all the candidates is -1, and the R2 value is 1.**

I must be doing something wrong, because I do see different slope patterns when I plot a single candidate's delta against the other 5:

[image: Chart of 6 candidates]

I'm using `sklearn.linear_model` and `statsmodels` in Python. Here's the summary output:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  Biden   R-squared:                       1.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  1.000
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                 5.559e+30
Date:                Fri, 27 Dec 2019   Prob (F-statistic):               0.00
Time:                        09:49:42   Log-Likelihood:                 51970.
No. Observations:                1689   AIC:                        -1.039e+05
Df Residuals:                    1683   BIC:                        -1.039e+05
Df Model:                           5                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const       1.732e-15   8.33e-16      2.079      0.038    9.79e-17    3.37e-15
Buttigieg     -1.0000   2.75e-16  -3.63e+15      0.000      -1.000      -1.000
Klobuchar     -1.0000   2.42e-16  -4.13e+15      0.000      -1.000      -1.000
Sanders       -1.0000   4.73e-16  -2.11e+15      0.000      -1.000      -1.000
Warren        -1.0000   3.76e-16  -2.66e+15      0.000      -1.000      -1.000
Yang          -1.0000   5.33e-16  -1.87e+15      0.000      -1.000      -1.000
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        1.526   Durbin-Watson:                   2.009
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.466   Jarque-Bera (JB):                1.498
Skew:                          -0.015   Prob(JB):                        0.473
Kurtosis:                       2.857   Cond. No.                         29.4
==============================================================================
```

Is there anything obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: If you post the data or the code you used to generate the data/model, it'd be much easier to understand what might be going on.

Comment: Got it — here's the Juypter notebook. The first half focuses on generating the data. https://github.com/arm5077/iowa-simulation/blob/master/Iowa%20caucus%20simulation.ipynb

Comment: The problem is that you're predicting Biden's change in votes from the other candidates' change in votes. If one candidate increases their votes, another candidate's votes has to decrease, and the candidate that loses a vote has to be Biden because the other candidates' voting changes are held constant (as specified by the model). I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to get out of the analysis, but it's likely a re-framing is necessary or maybe a different model.

Comment: My expectation is that the coefficients for Biden would approximate the behavior I've set for Biden voters. From notebook: Of all Biden voters, 50% will stay no matter what, 25% will go to Buttigieg, 10% will go to Klobuchar, 10% will go to Warren, 5% will go to the rest. So I'd see a larger coefficient for Buttigieg than Yang, for instance.

Comment: You are using regression to discover the mathematically necessary relation identified by @assumednormal: the coefficients are estimated without error. You're not tracking flow of voters, but only net votes gained and lost.  Flows are measured in terms of votes taken from candidate A and given to candidate B. With six candidates, that's 30 flow values with six linear relations, requiring a model with 24 parameters.

Comment: Ah, understood. My hope was to be able to infer flow through modeling something on net changes, since in real life, flow data isn't available — only the total voters per candidate per round.